# Counting passed seconds

Tags: python, pys60

How can we count the number of seconds
passed since the start of the day 0.00 ?
Is there a module 
function or do we have to do it ourselves?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime, time

now = datetime.now()
beginning_of_day = datetime.combine(now.date(), time(0))
print (now - beginning_of_day).seconds
```

See docs for `datetime` module [here](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html).

Comment: That solves the windows problem, but how to do it in pys60. There is no datetime module in it.

Comment: If you were interested in solution for pys60 you'd better specify that in the first place. Looks like you can add `datetime` module manually. Have a look at [this snippet](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/1614).

Comment: I initially tagged it pys60 but everytime I submitted my question an error (quality standards) kept coming ani I edited the title and tagged it python and it somehow worked. But, thanks It'll help me a lot