# I Need a simple and short python3 code that count secounds in a background process

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a text based flight simulator in python, but I can't really find out how I can count seconds in python.

I would like to write code that lets me write, while the time counts in the background. I also want a simple code like for example `Import Time` then do `time.sleep(1)`.

I tried to do this:

```
for takeoff_time in range(0,16):
    time.sleep(1)
```

Then:

```
while takeoff_time == (15):
break()
print ("Fly Crashed Before TakeOff ")
time.sleep(2)
os.system("cls")
main()
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have?

Comment: @arshajii It doesn't allow any other processes, since `time.sleep` essentially pauses the whole program.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156330/get-timer-ticks-in-python and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543725/counting-passed-seconds.

Comment: The problem is that i can't write at the same time as time.sleep...

Answer (score 2):

using the time module you can do:

start_time = time.time()

RUN THE PART OF THE PROGRAM YOU WANT TO MEASURE

print(time.time()-start_time)

or instead of printing it you can assign it to a variable to keep track of it

Answer (score 1):

In Python, you have `time.clock() and time.time()`

time.clock

```
start = time.clock()
... do something
elapsed = (time.clock() - start)
```

time.time

```
start = time.time()
... do something
elapsed = (time.time() - start)
```

For benchmarking code snippets, you should try using timeit: http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html

Comment: Almost... It's Just one problem. How can i use it in my flight simulator? I mean, How can i count secounds as an integer, ill like to write at the same time as the secounds is counting.